# Правильное ли использование async/await

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

Всем доброго времени суток.

Не так давно начал программировать на C#. По итогу написал следующее: [DIPlaylist](https://github.com/Notheireat/DIPlaylist) - программа создаёт [DI.FM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digitally_Imported) плейлист для AIMP с активированным премиумом на 7 дней.

Так как обучаюсь самостоятельно, то не могу оценить правильность кода. Впервые использовал async/await для того, чтобы основные задачи выполнялись вне главного потока, тем самым чтобы основное окно программы не подвисало. Но в текущем виде иногда замечаю, что это всё-таки происходит.

По итогу у меня возник вопрос, а правильно ли я использовал async/await? Так же буду премного благодарен за комментарии к остальному коду, для моего обучения это будет крайне полезно.

Код небольшой и в нём я старался комментировать все значимые и возможно непонятные на первый взгляд моменты.

Пример такого кода (вырезки):

```
private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar.Value++;
    // Получение письма с премиум-ссылкой
    statusLabel.Content = await TempMail.GetLetter();
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Settings.TmLetterID))
    {
        Status(false);
        return;
    }

    progressBar.Value++;
    // Создание и сохранение плейлиста
    statusLabel.Content = await Playlist.GoPlaylist();
    if (statusLabel.Content.ToString().ToLower().Contains("ошибка"))
    {
        Status(false);
        return;
    }
}


public static async Task<string> GetLetter()
{
    SetHeader();
    // 10 попыток с задержкой в 3 секунды на получение письма
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        });
        string responseBody = "";

        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(Settings.TmURL);
            responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "Проблема с доступом к " + Settings.TmURL;
        }

        Match match = new Regex("view\\/(.*?)\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Match(responseBody);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            Settings.TmLetterID = match.Groups[1].Value.Trim();
            return "Получение ключа на временный премиум...";
        }
    }
    return "Ошибка при получении письма с активацией";
}


public static async Task<string> GoPlaylist()
{
    try
    {
        List<string> channelsInfo = new List<string>();
        channelsInfo.Add($"#Name:Digitally Imported ({Settings.TmAddress}:{Settings.DiPass})");
        channelsInfo.Add("#Cursor:-1");

        JObject playlistJS = JObject.Parse(Settings.DiPlaylistJS);
        JToken[] channels = playlistJS["channels"].ToArray();

        channelsInfo.Add($"#Summary:{channels.Count().ToString()} / 00:00:00:00 / 0 B");
        channelsInfo.Add("#Flags:2047");
        channelsInfo.Add("#Group:Radio|1");

        int count = 0;
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            foreach (var data in channels)
            {
                count++;
                channelsInfo.Add($"#Track:{count}|http://prem2.di.fm:80/{data["key"].ToString()}_hi?{Settings.DiListenKey}||||{data["name"].ToString()}|0|0|||0|0|0");
            }

            File.WriteAllLines($@"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\Digitally Imported.aimppl", channelsInfo);
            return "Плейлист успешно сгенерирован!";
        });
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return "Ошибка при обработке плейлиста";
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы должны поместить код, о котором хотите спросить, в сам вопрос. Код на гитхабе может поменяться (и скорее всего будет меняться), поэтому в его нынешнем виде вопрос станет бесполезным для читателей через буквально несколько дней. Кроме того, вам имеет смысл вычленить из вашего кода только ту часть, которая имеет отношение к вопросу, потому что иначе это придётся делать отвечающим (а они ленятся, ведь это не их код).

Comment: Спасибо, исправил. Сразу не выделил часть кода, потому что в принципе там весь код имеет отношение к вопросу (по моему мнению).

Comment: А что делает метод `SetHeader`?

Comment: "SetHeader" добавляет к запросу заголовки. Так как мне необходимо делать несколько запросов с одними и теми же заголовками и дабы не повторять код, решил его вынести в метод.

Comment: Тут не совсем понятно. У вас один `httpClient`, который настраивается по-разному перед каждым запросом? А что будет, если во время ожидания отсылки одного запроса будет отправлен ещё и другой?

Comment: Не представлял такое возможным, соответственно не думал и о последствиях. Я так понимаю, вы советуете под каждый запрос создавать свой httpClient и соответственно настройки для оного, даже не смотря на то, что такой код по сути будет одинаковый почти для каждого запроса. Я правильно понял?

Comment: Ну, я бы и правда создавал локальный клиент. Настройки можно устанавливать тем же методов `SetHeaders`, который пускай работает не на глобальном, а на передаваемом в качестве параметра клиенте. Но я не сетевик, так что не знаю, как реально лучше.

Comment: Не нужно создавать отдельный `HttpClient`, он создан с расчетом на работу со множеством запросов/соединений.

Answer (score -1):

важно понимать, что конструкции `Task` могут быть разными. Например, `Task.Factory.StartNew` использует асинхронные машины состояний, а конструкция `Task.Run` запускает отдельный поток на ЦП. Это очень хорошо описано в  [документации Майкрософт по платформе .Net](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/#a-namebkmkthreadsa-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8).

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
     Thread.Sleep(3000);
});
```

Здесь ожидание реализовано не очень хорошо, т.к. очевидно, что создавать новый поток только лишь для того, чтобы отложить выполнение метода - глупо, т.к. это весьма затратно. Используйте `await Task.Delay(ms)`.
Это что касается метода, в котором вы получаете данные по сети. 
Если рассмотреть [другой пример](https://github.com/Notheireat/DIPlaylist/blob/master/Digitally%20Imported/Playlist.cs), то может возникнуть несколько вопросов. Самый первый: почему у вас половина метода в таске, а половина - нет ? Оберните всё в таск и уберите async / await

```
try {
       return Task.Run(() => DoSomething());
   } 
   catch 
   {}
```

Comment: Ах вон оно как... Век живи - век учись. Спасибо.

Comment: `Task.Factory.StartNew` и `Task.Run` -- это одно и то же с т.з. механизма работы.

Comment: в целом - да, но во втором случае задача помещается в пул потоков windows и выполняется в отдельном потоке

Comment: @Arthur, а что по  вашему происходит в первом случае, когда `Task.Factory.StartNew`?

Comment: @Arthur нет, они работают одинаково. Единственные отличия в том, что `Task.Run` автоматически разворачивает таски, а интерфейс `Task.Factory.StartNew` позволяет контролировать больше вещей. [Статья по теме](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/10/24/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/). Ну и на исходники можете взглянуть: [раз](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,298c51c20d5a4fad) и [два](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TaskFactory.cs,61f85d672e9eca30).